# upload JDA discord bot to heroku

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku, discord

Hi I am trying to upload my JDA discord bot to heroku but when i am trying to push it to heroku i am getting this error:

```
remote:        [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 20 source files to /tmp/build_b5079e7584c21a569003e4d9347d90d0/target/classes
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_b5079e7584c21a569003e4d9347d90d0/src/net/OFFWORLDMC/Musik/MusikController.java:[18,39] cannot find symbol
remote:          symbol:   variable volume
remote:          location: class net.OFFWORLDMC.Musik.MusikController
remote:        [INFO] 1 error
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  31.677 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-08T20:07:06Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project OffWorldMc: Compilation failure
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_b5079e7584c21a569003e4d9347d90d0/src/net/OFFWORLDMC/Musik/MusikController.java:[18,39] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR]   symbol:   variable volume
remote:        [ERROR]   location: class net.OFFWORLDMC.Musik.MusikController
remote:        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to offworldmc.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/offworldmc.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/offworldmc.git'
```

I haven't created any new file in my Directory 
Please help me
Thanks for every answer

Comment: now the build is devloped to heroku but i its status is offline

Answer (score 0):

`MusikController.java:[18,39] cannot find symbol`, there is a symbol on line 18 of MusikController.java that cannot be found.

Possible fix: `[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!` As the message says, build is platform dependent. This probably worked on your PC but the default platform encoding UTF-8 can't be used to read that certain symbol I mentioned earlier on the server.

Comment: now the build is devloped to heroku but i its status is offline